# Use same partial to add form to Create and Edit actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

When you create a new scaffolded item on VS it creates the views for Create and Edit actions that are almost identical, with the exception of the Edit view having an `@Html.HiddenFor` for your primary key.

Example of Edit view:

```
@model MyApp.Models.Destaque

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IdDestaque)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mensagem, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mensagem, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mensagem, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CaminhoImagem, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CaminhoImagem, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CaminhoImagem, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UrlLink, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UrlLink, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UrlLink, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

If I place all content from the `BeginForm` (including the `@using (...`) and keep the `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IdDestaque)` in a _Form partial, it doesn't allow me to create new rows.

If I remove the `@Html.HiddenFor` from the _Form partial, the Edit action does not work (ModelState is invalid).

So what is the right way to do this and keep the DRY principles? Removing the PK from the ModelState validation in my Edit action seems an "uggly" workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You should render the id of your model inside the view and use another overload for Html.BeginForm as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new{attr1 = value1, attr2 = value2}))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
    ...
}
```

You always make a post to the **EditAction**. In you controller you will then only need one POST action for Edit and two get actions one Create and other Edit.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   return View("Edit"); //return the edit view
}

public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var entity = manager.FetchById(id);
    if (entity == null)
       return HttpNotFound();

    //convert your entity to model (optional, but recommended)
    var model = Mapper.Map<ViewModel>(entity);

    //return your edit view with your model
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //work with your model

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Controller");
    }

    //at this point there is an error, so your must return your view
    return View(model);
}
```

Hope this helps!